# Getting 401 from browser but 200 from postman with Asp.net core and Identityserver 4

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, postman, identityserver4

I tried everything and I keep getting 401 error when I try to reach my api from a react App.
My Api is a asp.net core protected with Identity server.

From Postman, I can request an access token and call api and it works fine.
From the the browser, I can get a valid access token, but any api calls failed with 401.

The exact request that failed in the browser, works fine on postman (copy as cUrl from dev tool, then import in postman).

I'Ve tried both http and https, I'Ve check the order of element in startup, I'Ve configured the CORS...nothing.

I'm using the same web app both as Identity Server and Api server.

This is my startup file:

```
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Pesabooks.Api.Common;
using Pesabooks.Application;
using Pesabooks.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using Pesabooks.Domain.Session;
using Pesabooks.Infrastructure;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pesabooks.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
                    });
            });



            services.AddControllersWithViews()
                 .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<IPesabooksDbContext>()); ;

            services.AddApplication();
            services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration, Environment);

            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                  .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
                  {
                      options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";

                      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                      {
                          ValidateAudience = false,
                      };

                      //options.Audience = "pesabooks";
                      options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                  });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
                {
                    context.Response.Headers["Location"] = context.RedirectUri;
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

            });
   

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Pesabooks.Api", Version = "v1" });
                c.OperationFilter<AddRequiredHeaderParameter>();
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions { MinimumSameSitePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {

                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Pesabooks.Api v1"));
            }

            app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();
            // app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseTenantMiddleware();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                 );
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

this is my identityserver client settings:

```
{
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": [
      {
        "ClientId": "Pesabooks.WebApp",
        "ClientName": "Pesabooks Web App",
        "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "implicit" ],
        "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "api" ],
        "RequireClientSecret": false,
        "RedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:3000/signin-oidc" ],
        "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "http://localhost:3000/signout-oidc" ],
        "AllowedCorsOrigins": [ "http://localhost:3000" ],
        "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
        "Enabled": true
      },
      {
        "ClientName": "Pesabooks.IntegrationTests",
        "ClientId": "Pesabooks.IntegrationTests",
        "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "password" ],
        "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile" ],
        "ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "*****" } ],
        "Enabled": true
      },
      {
        "ClientName": "Postman",
        "ClientId": "postman",
        "RequirePkce": false,
        "AllowedGrantTypes": [ "authorization_code" ],
        "AllowOfflineAccess": true,
        "IdentityTokenLifetime": 86400,
        "AccessTokenLifetime": 86400,
        "RedirectUris": [ "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback" ],
        "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [ "https://www.getpostman.com" ],
        "AllowedCorsOrigins": [ "https://www.getpostman.com" ],
        "AllowedScopes": [ "openid", "profile", "email", "api" ],
        "ClientSecrets": [ { "Value": "*****" } ],
        "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
        "RequireConsent": false,
        "EnableLocalLogin": true,
        "Enabled": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is an example of a request that fail in the browser but works in postman:

```
 curl 'http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FAccounts%3FOnlySavings%3Dfalse%26IncludeDeactivated%3Dfalse' \
      -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
      -H 'Accept: application/json' \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjdBQjI4QUQzNEQ3OUMwOTNCMkY2NjZEQUU5MTYwQzczIiwidHlwIjoiYXQrand0In0.eyJuYmYiOjE2MTE1MDA4NDgsImV4cCI6MTYxMTUwNDQ0OCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MDAwL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IlBlc2Fib29rcy5XZWJBcHAiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjExNTAwODE4LCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsImp0aSI6IkYzRkE5MUIxRUM0MzIyNkRBNEZCNDU1QjQ2MTE1MzI5Iiwic2lkIjoiQTE3RDVDQjY3QTIxMDc0MjE4QzgyNTE1RjI5QjdGQUYiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTE1MDA4NDgsInNjb3BlIjpbIm9wZW5pZCIsInByb2ZpbGUiLCJhcGkiXSwiYW1yIjpbInB3ZCJdfQ.gGmUUmZNZLjhyY47diPXQHGXO0k1B8mss8FIdQuecFmp-SxRFls6nF7fU3bqQdQcadpIrZEjDGG2wth8IZIqg82K5L4jr9Nt8Rp8JMdvC-zn7TbHKV670QSYF6NIq5AKWNMi86oNfk9QYEIjM7p5DWjzSjH5LAmINQjwCNG0QhXccSqbUkmVxxsYQkCOfZnlsshrswP41ocNs1s_363v070Tc6ayrxBSYiqM5AbLs_5y4iSXgP1TzWdwxcavBng-vEA0lp5hU0ZNggmBid_GOrgKRfHNzv8518RfHtpa1VwptdkRMiba18t-HNezMw7WMh432Q6RxRvJGW6iq7S8eg' \
      -H 'psbk-tenant: 5' \
      -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36' \
      -H 'Sec-GPC: 1' \
      -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' \
      -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site' \
      -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' `
      -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
      -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/' \
      -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
      --compressed
```

This is what I got in the logs:

```
[11:28:48 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: http://localhost:3000

[11:28:48 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Services.InMemoryCorsPolicyService
Client list checked and origin: http://localhost:3000 is allowed

[11:28:48 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.CorsPolicyProvider
CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http://localhost:3000

[11:28:48 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[11:28:48 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint

[11:28:48 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
Start discovery request

[11:28:48 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

[11:28:48 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

[11:28:48 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /connect/checksession matched to endpoint type Checksession

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Checksession, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint

[11:28:48 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint for /connect/checksession

[11:28:48 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.CheckSessionEndpoint
Rendering check session result
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share the request made in the browser? you can capture it via devtools.

Comment: What does the WWW-Authenticate header say in the 401 response header? An example header can look like this:
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

Comment: @MariusSteinbach the cUrl I posted is the request  made in the browser

Comment: @ToreNestenius there is no WWW-Authenticate header in the response

Comment: What does the logs say? set the log level for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication to verbose

Comment: @ToreNestenius how do I do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a test and created a separate web api project and it worked straight away.

Using the same server for both identity server and my api was a bad idea and for some reasons that doesn't work.

The solution: Have a dedicated web app for identity server

Answer (score 0):

To help you out debugging you should configure your logs and show the debug output from them. In IdentityServer solutions you typically control that in the program.cs class, like this example below taken from [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Templates/blob/main/src/IdentityServer4InMem/Program.cs):

Just set the log level to Debug to see more insights in your operation.

```
  Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            // uncomment to write to Azure diagnostics stream
            //.WriteTo.File(
            //    @"D:\home\LogFiles\Application\identityserver.txt",
            //    fileSizeLimitBytes: 1_000_000,
            //    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
            //    shared: true,
            //    flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Code)
            .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: I've updated the post with the logs. One information I forgot to mention is I'm using the same server both as Identity server and Api server. Just in case

Comment: You need the log from JwtBearer, in this namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

Comment: There is nothing in the log. I realised that even postman isn't working unless I had already authenticated via the authorization panel.

I think mixing the identityserver and the api within the same app wasn't a good idea. I will separate them into two distincts web app

Comment: Yes, you should really separate identityserver, the api and the client, other wise you will end up in a disaster eventually.